# BigQueryIO.Read later in the pipeline (not PBegin)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, apache-beam

We have a scenario where we need to have BigQuery.Read later in the pipeline (not at PBegin). Is there a way to implement it?

We are trying to run sequence of steps where we load a pcollection to bigquery table and then fetch data from that table (with some filters) after the load for our next steps. We are able to do this in multiple pipelines having bigqueryio.read at the starting of each pipeline. However, it would bea easier for our batch control if we can have it in single dataflow pipeline (loading entire bigquery tables initially and working completely off that pcollection is expensive)

Comment: There's not a lot of information to work with here. What's the problem you're trying to solve? What have you got so far? Please share some code and elaborate on your question..

Comment: Updated my question to provide more details

Comment: i think you still need to provide more info to get an answer here. My understanding is that within the same pipeline, you want to write data into a BQ table, then query that table and send the results to another sink. Are you reading from an unbounded source? If so, maybe you could do what you're looking for BigQueryIO.write() on one side and then with BigQueryIO.Read fromQuery() on the other. Then again, if you're streaming into BigQuery, you have no guarantee that you'll be reading exactly what you want (no repeated data for example) when you query that table.

Comment: For an unbounded source, another solution could be to write into BigQuery using BatchLoads, triggered with a elementCountAtLeast() trigger so that you know how many elements you write at each batch. Then, you can query just these rows that were last written. An alternative option could be to have two transforms process your input data, one writing to BigQuery and another doing the filtering that you want (not in BigQuery but instead with an equivalent ParDo) with the latter eventually writing in your "other" sink.

Comment: All in all, the above might be irrelevant or overcomplicating a simple problem. So, please provide more details: where are you reading from? What do your elements look like? How do you want to filter them? Where do you want to write?